# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory Spring and Hibernate3.6.0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am working on a web application using spring and hibernate, and after finishing the mapping of my beans, i ran a JUnit test to check if the mapping is correct and i got the following error:

```
> java.lang.AssertionError: Error creating bean with name
> 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
> [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
> exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
> UP_EBOUTIQUE] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory    at
> org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)     at
> org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)   at
> com.msecmaroc.msec.testJPA.test1(testJPA.java:17)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>   at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>   at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>   at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>   at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
>   at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Console log:!!

```
> INFO :
> org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext -
> Refreshing
> org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6f79caec:
> startup date [Fri Jun 16 07:58:07 CEST 2017]; root of context
> hierarchy INFO :
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader -
> Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource
> [applicationContext.xml] INFO :
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
> - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated.
> The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is
> automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver
> class is generally unnecessary.INFO :
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded
> JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
> 
> INFO :
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -
> Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit
> 'UP_EBOUTIQUE' INFO : org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version -
> Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.0.Final INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
> INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4
> java.sql.Timestamp handling INFO : org.hibernate.ejb.Version -
> Hibernate EntityManager 3.6.0.Final INFO :
> org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>   name: UP_EBOUTIQUE  ...] INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder -
> Binding entity from annotated class:
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Commande INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Commande on table commande INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Client INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Client on table Client INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Depot INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Depot on table depot INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Ligne_Commande INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Ligne_Commande on table ligne_commande
> INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from
> annotated class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Famille_Dechets INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Famille_Dechets on table famille_dechet
> INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from
> annotated class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Role INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Role on table Role INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Particulier INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Transporteur INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Societe INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Contrat INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Contrat on table contrat INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Type_Traitement INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Type_Traitement on table type_traitement
> INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from
> annotated class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Offre INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Offre on table offre INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Produit INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Produit on table produit INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Type_client INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Type_client on table type_client INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Stock INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Stock on table stock INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated
> class: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Intervention INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Intervention on table intervention INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection:
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Commande.listOperation -> ligne_commande
> INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping
> collection: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Client.commandes -> commande
> INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping
> collection: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Client.listOffre -> offre INFO
> : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection:
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Depot.stock -> stock INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection:
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Famille_Dechets.produits -> produit INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection:
> com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Type_Traitement.listeoperation ->
> ligne_commande INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder -
> Mapping collection: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Offre.listProduit ->
> produit INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder -
> Mapping collection: com.msecmaroc.msec.entities.Type_client.client ->
> Client INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator
> not found: ignoring INFO :
> org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable
> to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the
> classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled. INFO :
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
> Destroying singletons in
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7a187f14:
> defining beans
> [datasource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor];
> root of factory hierarchy
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
    <persistence-unit name="UP_EBOUTIQUE"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">


    <!-- Information de la base de donnes -->

    <bean id="datasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/msecmaroc"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>


    <!--Spring configuration -->
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="UP_EBOUTIQUE"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.msecmaroc</groupId>
    <artifactId>msec</artifactId>
    <name>MsecMarocV1</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Junitclasstest.java

```
public class testJPA {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        try {
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext app = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    new String[] { "applicationContext.xml" });
            assertTrue(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            assertTrue(e.getMessage(),false);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

For the moment i just created four entities

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idUser;

    @Column(name="userName" , nullable=false)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="password" , nullable=false)
    private String password;


    private boolean activated;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="idUser")
    private Collection<Role> roles;



    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }
    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public boolean isActivated() {
        return activated;
    }
    public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }
    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public User() {
        super();
    }
    public User(Long idUser, String userName, String password, boolean activated, Collection<Role> roles) {
        super();
        this.idUser = idUser;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.activated = activated;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

Role.java

```
@Entity

public class Role implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idRole;
    private String roleName;
    private User user;
    public Role(Long idRole, String roleName, User user) {
        super();
        this.idRole = idRole;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Role() {
        super();
    }
    public Long getIdRole() {
        return idRole;
    }
    public void setIdRole(Long idRole) {
        this.idRole = idRole;
    }
    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }
    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


}
```

Client.java

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type_client_soc_par", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idClient;

    @Column(name="matricule", nullable=false)
    private String matricule;

    @Column(name="nomCLient", nullable=false)
    private String nomClient;

    @Column(name="emailCLient", nullable=false)
    private String emailCLient;

    @Column(name="matricule", nullable=false)
    private String numTelephone;

    @Column(name="matricule", nullable=false)
    private String adresse;


    // Constructeur sans parametres
    public Client() {

    }


    public int getIdClient() {
        return idClient;
    }


    public void setIdClient(int idClient) {
        this.idClient = idClient;
    }


    public String getMatricule() {
        return matricule;
    }


    public void setMatricule(String matricule) {
        this.matricule = matricule;
    }


    public String getNomClient() {
        return nomClient;
    }


    public void setNomClient(String nomClient) {
        this.nomClient = nomClient;
    }


    public String getEmailCLient() {
        return emailCLient;
    }


    public void setEmailCLient(String emailCLient) {
        this.emailCLient = emailCLient;
    }


    public String getNumTelephone() {
        return numTelephone;
    }


    public void setNumTelephone(String numTelephone) {
        this.numTelephone = numTelephone;
    }


    public String getAdresse() {
        return adresse;
    }


    public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }
```

Societe.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Societe")
public class Societe extends Client implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="nomResponsable", nullable=false)
    private String nomResponsable;

    @Column(name="emailResponsable", nullable=false)
    private String emailResponsable;

    @Column(name="telResponsable", nullable=false)
    private String telResponsable;

    @Column(name="nomSuperieur", nullable=false)
    private String nomSuperieur;

    @Column(name="emailSuperieur", nullable=false)
    private String emailSuperieur;

    @Column(name="telSuperieur", nullable=false)
    private String telSuperieur;

    @Column(name="commentaire", nullable=false)
    private String commentaire;

    //constructeur sans parametre
    public Societe() {

    }

    public String getNomResponsable() {
        return nomResponsable;
    }

    public void setNomResponsable(String nomResponsable) {
        this.nomResponsable = nomResponsable;
    }

    public String getEmailResponsable() {
        return emailResponsable;
    }

    public void setEmailResponsable(String emailResponsable) {
        this.emailResponsable = emailResponsable;
    }

    public String getTelResponsable() {
        return telResponsable;
    }

    public void setTelResponsable(String telResponsable) {
        this.telResponsable = telResponsable;
    }

    public String getNomSuperieur() {
        return nomSuperieur;
    }

    public void setNomSuperieur(String nomSuperieur) {
        this.nomSuperieur = nomSuperieur;
    }

    public String getEmailSuperieur() {
        return emailSuperieur;
    }

    public void setEmailSuperieur(String emailSuperieur) {
        this.emailSuperieur = emailSuperieur;
    }

    public String getTelSuperieur() {
        return telSuperieur;
    }

    public void setTelSuperieur(String telSuperieur) {
        this.telSuperieur = telSuperieur;
    }

    public String getCommentaire() {
        return commentaire;
    }

    public void setCommentaire(String commentaire) {
        this.commentaire = commentaire;
    }
```

What's weird about it, is that if i removre the super class and the subclass and i leave only the Role and User everything work fine and the schema is created, but if i add the two classes the same problem occurs

Comment: Have you tried to change the mysql driver to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`?

Comment: Yes i have but the same exception occured.

Comment: Could you please provide more logs as this contains info messages only so it's not that helpful. Also, I'm not sure your persistence setup is seen when you're creating the context this way. I guess persistence.xml is simple being ignored.

Comment: With SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy you should not define non-nullable columns in child entities.

[link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance)